# How to rebuild main menu in IB

Tags: xcode, menu

I accidentally deleted the Main Menu menu from IB and now I have a hard time to reconstruct it. I am using Xcode 4.0. Is there anyway to recreate that?

Answer (score -2):

You mean main menu from the menu bar for a mac software ?

If yes, you can simply drag'n drop an NSMenuItem from the IB inspector to your menu bar.

PS : I'm not sure to have understood your question ...

Comment: Sort of. I deleted from inside Xcode (4.0) the whole main menu (generated by default) in the mainmenu.xib file, I had no way to recreated it. And I ended up recreating the whole app

Comment: I don't own yet xCode 4.0 so maybe that why I am a little confused, sorry. I guess that in the 4.0 you have an objects library (with NSButton, NSImageView, etc...) and it certainly must have an NSMenuBar object or smth like that ...

Comment: It still has those framework components. But I wanted to manually create the Main Menu, not thru code. :)

Comment: for me 'manually' means by the code ... and 'automatically' means by IB... but now, what is bothering you ? I am a bit confused sorry... you have those framework components you said... so what is missing ?